# how to create a dynamic form in angular 5 in very simple steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to learn how to create dynamic form in Angular v5.

I know how to deal with reactive form but now there's a necessity for me to learn dynamic form. Can any one here explain with an example?

Note: the example should be very clear and very useful for beginners like me!

Comment: it may help you https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Answer (score 0):

There's already a pretty good [guide to dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form). It has a long version. A very simplified version is: 
You create classes and templates for each possible form element, a class for an input, a class for a dropdown. When you recieve data with structure like, for example

```
[{
    "name":"input 1",
    "type":"input"
  },
  {
    "name":"input 2",
    "type":"input"
  },
  {
    "name":"drop down 1",
    "type":"dropdown"
  }
]
```

Angular will assemble a form, based on the classes and html tamplates you previously created.

PS

Please, spend time and read the official tutorial, it is much more fun, than my explanation :)

Comment: Hey bro it is tough form me to understand from https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form this link can you please paste a simple code here for me